# Can we have the comics removed?

Tags: discussion, captcha

The captcha is irritating enough already

[image]

can we at least turn off these comics (which seem to be a new feature).

Comment: The image was chosen on [this previous thread](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/969/ideas-for-404-captcha-error-images). As I recall, there wasn't much of a discussion; Jin started the thread and before the day was out he had launched the site with the top two posts. Perhaps you should post an answer there suggesting "no image".

Answer (score 10):

The CAPTCHAs are there to reduce spammer rate when a high-rep user gets compromised. See
[*My reputation is 100 and I still get captcha!*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67554/my-reputation-is-100-and-i-still-get-captcha) (from MSO):

> Jeff once said that **everyone, including moderators, are asked for CAPTCHAs in case their account gets compromised.** With that being said you will see less of them after you reach 10,000 reputation.

Answer (score 4):

Captcha should just be turned off for all users with over 500 rep.

Comment: A minimal cutoff (50, 100 or whatever is needed) may be needed to reduce spam, but beyond that there should be no rating-based gradation in ease of posting.  If anything one wants to get the lower-rated users to post whenever they can contribute, not exacerbate a situation where 20 people are 80+ percent of the site.

Comment: Captcha for frequent edits is pointless. I think we do need it for frequently posted new questions/answers though, irrespective of rep.